# Author per locale

Tags: users, localization, author

For each locale I have a different author which I want to display on the front-end. But at this point author does not seem to per locale? Is the only way to achieve this by adding  a users field?

Answer (score 2):

Author fields aren't translatable, so if you change the author in one locale this would apply for all locales.

As you say, you could create a simple User field that is translatable, where you could set a user as being the 'Author' which you could then output on the front-end.

This would work, but in Craft's eyes the true Author will always be the same user for every locale.

Comment: I just made this a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7274793-set-author-per-locale).